# Fullcalender - Allow some events draggable and some events non draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Is it possible to put a restriction on some events on fullcalendar, which can't be draggable or resizable?

I mean some events can be draggable and some can't be draggable.

Answer (score 1):

The `editable` property on the `Event` object is probably what you're after, cf. [the docs](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/).

> **`editable`** `true` or `false`. Optional. Overrides the master [editable](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/editable/) option for this single event.

**Example:**

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: [
        {
            title   : 'draggable/resizable',
            start   : '2010-01-01'
        },
        {
            title   : 'locked',
            start   : '2010-01-05',
            end     : '2010-01-07',
            editable: false
        }
    ]
});
```

---

Also worth noting is the possibility to *revert* drag / resize events retrospectively via the `revertFunc` on [`eventResize`](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/eventResize/) and [`eventDrop`](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/eventDrop/).

Comment: I want to use disable editable for some events on calender, not for all events

Comment: @user2857239 Exactly. The property is on the `Event` object. I have added an example.

Comment: Can you help me in one more thing? Please visit my post :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20542056/fullcalender-can-we-add-custom-data-to-our-event-json-data